# Is it possible to return a mock object for a method call based on a local variable in the actual class?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

Say I have this class:

```
public class RealClass {

    public static void method1(String accountID) {
        AccountObject accountObj = soapService.getAccountObject(accountID)
    }

}
```

And I'm writing a mock as such:

```
AccountObject accountObj = new AccountObject();
accountObj.setGoodAccount(false);
when(soapService.getAccountObject(anyString())).thenReturn(accountObj);
```

However, I want the AccountObject returned to have its "goodAccount" field set based on the accountID that's being evaluated in RealClass. So for example, if the current method call is method1("abc123"), then I'd want to set goodAccount to be true. If the method call is method1("def456"), then I'd want goodAccount to be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two account objects and specify the accountID instead of `anyString()`

```
AccountObject goodAccount = new AccountObject();
AccountObject badAccount = new AccountObject();

goodAccount.setGoodAccount(true);
badAccount.setGoodAccount(false);

when(soapService.getAccountObject("abc123")).thenReturn(goodAccount);
when(soapService.getAccountObject("def456")).thenReturn(badAccount);
```